# Remote Administration

Tags: c#

I would like to access the file from one pc to other pc in a remote location and also want to share them..something like remote desktop application

Comment: Why don't you use remote desktop? (Or the remote desktop ActiveX control)

Comment: This might be better suited to SuperUser...

Comment: How is this related to C#?  Are you looking for a tool to for remote access written in C#?  If so, the Terminals project on CodePlex might suit your needs (http://www.codeplex.com/Wikipage?ProjectName=Terminals).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595170/c-non-windows-remote-desktop) post about C# Non-Windows Remote Desktop

The best voted answer said to check out [VNC](http://dotnetvnc.sourceforge.net/)

or

[VNC Sharp](http://cdot.senecac.on.ca/projects/vncsharp/)

Answer (score 0):

VNC is OK, Windows Remote Desktop is good, DameWare Mini Remote Control is better IMHO: http://www.dameware.com/downloads/default.aspx#dmrc

If you are in a mixed platform environment then VNC is probably your best bet (though RDP is pretty well supported across platforms these days). If you only care about windows and you have a little $$ to spend, I highly recommend DameWare.